# Memory Leaks in Class method objective -c

Tags: objective-c

i had a problem with memory leak in this below code ,
potential leak of an object in line 39,

and here line 39 is ,[self alloc] init];

```
+ (UploaderThread *)sharedUploaderThread {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (_sharedUploaderThread == nil) 
        {
            [[self alloc] init];

        }
    }
    return _sharedUploaderThread;
}
```

plz help me , wer i did the mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not assigning the value to `_sharedUploaderThread`. Do

```
_sharedUploaderThread = [[self alloc] init];
```

Since you were not assigning the value, you were leaking.

Answer (score 1):

You are not storing the pointer to the allocated object. Think you've ment:

```
_sharedUploaderThread = [[self alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

You never set _sharedUploaderThread equal to the [[self alloc] init]. Thereby leaking it.